# Iterate trough JSON with JavaScript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a structure:

```
var j = { a: { optional: true, type: 'string' },
  b: { optional: true, type: 'string' },
  c: { optional: true, type: 'string' } 
}
```

How to iterate trough each element so that is printing on a screen as a new line ?

Thanks.

Comment: I got a structure like that from another service.. Also that 'duplicate' does not deal with nested...

Comment: ```for (var key in j) {
    if (j.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
```